# Python/Matplotlib - Find the highest value of a group of bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, drawing

I have this image from Matplotlib : 
[image]

I would like to write for each category (`cat i with i in [1-10]` in the figure) the highest value and its corresponding legend on the graphic. 
Below you can find visually what I would like to achieve : 
[image]

The thing is the fact that I don't know if it is possible because of the way of plotting from matplotlib.

Basically, this is the part of the code for drawing multiple bars :

```
# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (9,9))
index = np.arange(len_category)
if multiple:
    bar_width = 0.3
else :
    bar_width = 1.5
opacity = 1.0
#test_array contains test1 and test2
cmap = get_cmap(len(test_array))

for i in range(len(test_array)):
        count = count + 1
        current_label = test_array[i]
        rects = plt.bar(index-0.2+bar_width*i, score_array[i], bar_width, alpha=opacity, color=np.random.rand(3,1),label=current_label )

plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by Categories')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, categories_array)
plt.legend()        

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and this is the part I have added in order to do what I would like to achieve. But it searches the max across all the bars in the graphics. For example, the max of test1 will be in cat10 and the max of test2 will be cat2. Instead, I would like **to have the max for each category**.

```
 for i in range(len(test_array)):
       count = count + 1
       current_label = test_array[i]
       rects = plt.bar(index-0.2+bar_width*i, score_array[i], bar_width,alpha=opacity,color=np.random.rand(3,1),label=current_label )

       max_score_current = max(score_array[i])
       list_rect = list()
       max_height = 0
       #The id of the rectangle who get the highest score
       max_idx = 0

         for idx,rect in enumerate(rects):
            list_rect.append(rect)
            height = rect.get_height()
            if height > max_height:
                max_height = height
                max_idx = idx
            highest_rect = list_rect[max_idx]
            plt.text(highest_rect.get_x() + highest_rect.get_width()/2.0, max_height,  str(test_array[i]),color='blue', fontweight='bold')
         del list_rect[:]
```

Do you have an idea about how I can achieve that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually better to keep data generation and visualization separate. Instead of looping through the bars themselves, just get the necessary data prior to plotting. This makes everything a lot more simple.

So first create a list of labels to use and then loop over the positions to annotate then. In the code below the labels are created by mapping the  `argmax` of a column array to the test set via a dictionary.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test1 = [6,4,5,8,3]
test2 = [4,5,3,4,6]

labeldic = {0:"test1", 1:"test2"}

a = np.c_[test1,test2]
maxi = np.max(a, axis=1)
l = ["{} {}".format(i,labeldic[j]) for i,j in zip(maxi, np.argmax(a, axis=1))]

for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    plt.bar(np.arange(a.shape[0])+(i-1)*0.3, a[:,i], width=0.3, align="edge", 
            label = labeldic[i])

for i in range(a.shape[0]): 
    plt.annotate(l[i], xy=(i,maxi[i]), xytext=(0,10), 
                 textcoords="offset points", ha="center")
plt.margins(y=0.2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Thomas Yep, you are right, it's not entirely clear from the question; I oriented on the "visual" description of the desired outcome, more than on the text.

Comment: Perfect ! It works well in this way ! I got your point ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

From your question it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but assuming that you want the relative height of each bar in one group printed above that bar, here is one way to achieve that:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

score_array = np.random.rand(2,10)
index = np.arange(score_array.shape[1])
test_array=['test1','test2']


opacity = 1
bar_width = 0.25

for i,label in enumerate(test_array):
    rects = plt.bar(index-0.2+bar_width*i, score_array[i], bar_width,alpha=opacity,label=label)
    heights = [r.get_height() for r in rects]
    print(heights)
    rel_heights = [h/max(heights) for h in heights]
    idx = heights.index(max(heights))

    for i,(r,h, rh) in enumerate(zip(rects, heights, rel_heights)):
        plt.text(r.get_x() + r.get_width()/2.0, h, '{:.2}'.format(rh), color='b', fontweight ='bold', ha='center')

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help ! It is not exactly what I'm looking for (a guy just posted a solution) but it is very helpful. So thank you.